# Creating Dynamic User Interface Using ArrayList

Tags: c#

I am creating program which adds certain items to catalogue, I send all the items from **library form** to **catalogue form**. Each time I click add button new item appears in catalogue form. Also each item detail is saved in **ArrayList NewItem** and consequently added to static class **Item**.

All items are added programmatically to **Catalogue form**, however each time I add new item it overwrites the previous so that catalogue form looks similar as in picture, except it more like this:

> Rambo 1
>
> Rambo 1
>
> Rambo 2

Any advice?

This is sample of code which adds the new items.

```
ArrayList hello = new ArrayList();

// NewItem is ArrayList into which all the item details are originally added

private void addItem(ArrayList NewItem)
{
    foreach (object obj in NewItem)
    {
        Item st = (Item)obj;
        String iname= st.IName.ToString();

        int helloe = hello.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < helloe ; i++)
        {
            hello.Add(new Label());
            System.Drawing.Point p = 
                new System.Drawing.Point(35, 120+ helloe * 25);

            (hello[helloe] as Label).Location = p;
            (hello[helloe] as Label).Size = new System.Drawing.Size(80, 20);

            (hello[helloe] as Label).Text = iname.ToString();

            Catalouge.Controls.Add(hello[helloe] as Label);
```

[image: sample form]

Comment: +1 for mentioning Rambo.

Comment: why ArrayList and why not List<Item>?

Comment: legacy stuff, doesn't really affect how program works